# Possible to access other stages variables in Capistrano?

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Let's say I have 3 files for 3 stages: `production.rb` `staging.rb` and `old.rb`

Is there any way in a rake task, when running something like `deploy production transfer:site` to access variables set in both production.rb and old.rb?